# Rails custom update form redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get this one form to redirect back to the page the user is on after submitting.

**photos.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(i, :p => 'backtophoto') do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
      <%= f.file_field :image, class: "form-control" %>
   </div>
   <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Upload", :class => 'cta primary' %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

**items_controller.rb**

```
def update
    if @item.update(item_params)
      if params[:p] = 'backtophoto'
        redirect_to photos_path
      else
        redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully updated.'
      end
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

The problem is that "IF" logic isn't working... it's always doing a redirect back to photos_path. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add the params to the submit button:

```
<%= form_for(i) do |f| %>
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.file_field :image, class: "form-control" %>
              </div>
               <div class="actions">
                <%= f.submit "Upload", :class => 'cta primary', name: "photo", value: "Upload" %>
              </div>
            <% end %>
```

And then check in the controller this way:

```
def update
    if @item.update(item_params)
      if params[:photo] == 'Upload'
        redirect_to photos_path
      else
        redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully updated.'
      end
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning value to `params[:p]` instead of comparing.
`params[:p] = 'backtophoto'`  assigns value whereas
`params[:p] == 'backtophoto'` or `params[:p] === 'backtophoto'` checks if true.

```
def update
    if @item.update(item_params)
      if params[:p] == 'backtophoto'
        redirect_to photos_path
      else
        redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully updated.'
      end
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

Hope this is clear.

Comment: That is clear, but it is still not redirecting back to photos_path after updating. It's redirecting to @item.

Comment: Can the params be set like that in the form?